# Multiple emails for one domain

Tags: email-server, domain, google, domain-transferring

currently I have google workspace emails account and webmail emails accounts on the same domain. The challenge am having is only google workspace emails can send/receive emails but webmails emails can only send mails but not able to receive emails. Please I need help on how to set up both emails (google workspace emails & webmail emails powered by round cube) to send/receive emails on the same domain. Please I will appreciate step by step guide to do this. Thank you all.

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* hack it together *somehow*, by having either one deliver mail both locally and externally. As you don't control googles SMTP servers, this has to be configured on your end, and your servers will have to be default MX.

Will google accept not being listed as MX? They probably do checks, and may complain a *lot* that they're not MX. In addition it will not solve e-mail send from one account to another account on the Google platform; it will only be delivered to the google accounts *probabbly*.

This kind of setup you can make work if you control all implicated servers, or it's supported by the vendors. Not so in this case.

In short; unless you know what you are doing, don't do this. It's asking for problems.

Comment: thank you for your response, I appreciate

Comment: Note that what you *can* do is use subdomains, e.g. foo.example.com -> gmail, bar.example.com -> your MX.

Comment: Google is fine with not being main MX, but you should set up google to allow the MX (which disables SPF checks for mails coming thru that transport)

Comment: @NikiZe thank you for your response, please how do I achieve that?